# Why recyclerview.setOnCickListener(this) not clickable?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am trying to set a simple click to a recyclerview with a inner view.onclicklistener in my fragment. My question is, why it does not have any onClick callback when I click in the recyclerview area?

My code is as below:

```
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            
            binding.list.recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            binding.recyclerview.setClickable(true);
            binding.recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
            binding.recyclerview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Log.d("log", "Clicked");
                }
            });
            
        }
```

Comment: Why do want to set onclick on the recyclerview and not on the item?

Answer (score 0):

`binding.recyclerview.setOnClickListener` line will make `RecyclerView` clickable itself and you are probably looking for click listener fired when any list item/child of `RecyclerView` will be clicked. in that case use class in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick) and set it up like this:

```
binding.recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, recyclerView ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // do whatever
      }

      @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // do whatever
      }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is just because you have to perform click an event from the adapter class,
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick) for more references.